# Oracle Query giving error "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM RHSTRYWLN7.RESULT R
   INNER JOIN RHSTRYWLN7.PRODUCT P ON P.PRODUCT_CODE=R.PRODUCT_CODE
   WHERE SOURCE_GUID='i0ad0105800000151b126c1c49def32b4'
     AND DELETED='F'
     AND DATE_CREATED > systimestamp-90
     AND DATE_CREATED < systimestamp) AS A
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT S.result_guid,
          count(document_guid) DocCount
   FROM RHSTRYWLN7.RESULT S
   INNER JOIN RHSTRYWLN7.document D ON D.result_guid=S.Result_guid
   WHERE SOURCE_GUID='i0ad0105800000151b126c1c49def32b4'
     AND DELETED='F'
     AND DATE_CREATED > systimestamp-90
     AND DATE_CREATED < systimestamp
   GROUP BY S.result_guid) AS B ON A.Result_guid=B.Result_guid
```

Am trying to run the above query in sqldeveloper and getting error saying:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

When I run the sub queries independently it runs fine. What could be the issue?

Comment: Remove the as before the aliases

Comment: Oracle doesn't like `AS` for a table alias, only for columns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the *As* when giving a name to a subquery. You can try the below

```
SELECT *
    FROM
      (SELECT *
       FROM RHSTRYWLN7.RESULT R
       INNER JOIN RHSTRYWLN7.PRODUCT P ON P.PRODUCT_CODE=R.PRODUCT_CODE
       WHERE SOURCE_GUID='i0ad0105800000151b126c1c49def32b4'
         AND DELETED='F'
         AND DATE_CREATED > systimestamp-90
         AND DATE_CREATED < systimestamp) A
    INNER JOIN
      (SELECT S.result_guid,
              count(document_guid) DocCount
       FROM RHSTRYWLN7.RESULT S
       INNER JOIN RHSTRYWLN7.document D ON D.result_guid=S.Result_guid
       WHERE SOURCE_GUID='i0ad0105800000151b126c1c49def32b4'
         AND DELETED='F'
         AND DATE_CREATED > systimestamp-90
         AND DATE_CREATED < systimestamp
       GROUP BY S.result_guid) B ON A.Result_guid=B.Result_guid
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of `AS` keyword for table alias is not **ANSI SQL** standard. And is not supported in **Oracle**.

The same applies for the **sub-query** in your case which is used in the **FROM** clause, called as an **in-line view**. Don't use the `AS` keyword.

Comment: Of course `AS` for aliases is Standard SQL, it's just optional. Nobody knows why Oracle insist on not allowing it for table, but for column aliases. It makes reading SQL much easier when you got syntax highlighting enabled :-)  And Standard SQL names the  *in-line view/sub-query* **Derived Table**.

Comment: Yeah, derived table :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query and check

```
SELECT R.*,
       count(document_guid) OVER (PARTITION BY result_guid) DocCount
  FROM RHSTRYWLN7.RESULT R
 INNER JOIN RHSTRYWLN7.PRODUCT P 
    ON P.PRODUCT_CODE=R.PRODUCT_CODE
 INNER JOIN RHSTRYWLN7.document D 
    ON D.result_guid=R.Result_guid
 WHERE SOURCE_GUID='i0ad0105800000151b126c1c49def32b4'
   AND DELETED='F'
   AND DATE_CREATED > systimestamp-90
   AND DATE_CREATED < systimestamp
```

Comment: You should include an explanation of why the code you're suggesting solves the problem.

Comment: @Nanhydrin here we join product and document table on result.Predicates for both the select seems to be same.Analytic function count over partition by will give the count after grouping by result_guid(PARTITION clause is used for grouping the records).